# Jquery отследить нажатие input

Tags: jquery

Как отследить нажатие на такую кнопку через jquery?

```
<input type="submit" name="SomeName" value="submit_value" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="test_button" tabindex="2" data-disable-with="someinfohere">
```

Кнопку желательно заселектить по id + class (если это возможно)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $('#test_button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right').on('click', function () {
        console.log('Кнопка нажата');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="SomeName" value="submit_value" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="test_button" tabindex="2" data-disable-with="someinfohere">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#test_button.btn').click(function(){
  alert('Произошло нажатие!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="SomeName" value="submit_value" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="test_button" tabindex="2" data-disable-with="someinfohere">
```